# Why does a "Verified" Google OAuth Consent screen still have a user cap?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-developers-console

My app is now "Verified", but the cap still shows 100. What am I missing? Do I need to do something else? Once again, the instructions provided by Google are confusing and not clear.

[image]

The (2) Sensitive Scopes I'm using say "verified" with a green checkbox.

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865

Sounds like the user cap will still show (no idea why), but it doesn't apply if I'm only requesting approved sensitive or restricted scopes. Can someone from Google please verify this? I don't want to run into a user cap problem in the future.

Comment: When you run your app doesn't it still show unverified screen?

Comment: Nope, it does not. I'm able to walk through the 0Auth process without the "unverified" warning screen popping up.

Comment: Wow, the app was "Verified" but then I changed the logo because it was too big for the space (no indication of the size by the way). That was easy enough. I just now checked the Consent page, and it said something about "Submit for verification". I clicked the button, and it walked me through yet another verification process with the Trust and Safety team. I have built all kinds of integrations. This is by far the most confusing and convoluted process.

Comment: Once your app is verified you cannot change anything.

Comment: correction once your app is verified you can change some things but it will often require you to go through the process again.   Depending on what you change your app will continue to work in the previous status

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo - Yes, I should have clarified that verification would be needed if anything is changed.

Comment: I just received another "Verified" status for my project. I'm not sure if this is the final verification from the Trust and Safety team. How would I know? Thanks!

Comment: So whats the final answer to this? Does the `OAuth user cap` apply for verified apps or not? If not why is that even shown in the Consent screen on cloud console ?

Comment: I recommend that you open a Google Cloud support ticket. Stack Overflow is not Google support. Most of us are engineers/admins/architects that **volunteer** our time helping others. Given that Google is changing verification requirements, I recommend that you get an official answer from Google thru authorized support channels.